# EntityManagerFactory is closed when dynamic load persistence data in java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

```
main()
{   
 createEntityManagerFactory(model.getDriver(), model.getUrl(), model.getUser(), model.getPassword());
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public static void createEntityManagerFactory(String driver, String url, String username, String password) {

            Map<String, String> persistenceMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", driver);
            persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", url);
            persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", username);
            persistenceMap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", password);

            try {
                if (entityManagerFactory == null)
                    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("XYZAPI", persistenceMap);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            }
        }

        public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
            return entityManagerFactory;
        }
```

This is my code which call on server Startup.

And this my get Entity Manager function.

```
 public static EntityManager getDBManager() {
     EntityManager entityManager = null;
     EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =
     Configuration.getEntityManagerFactory();
     if(entityManagerFactory != null){
     entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
     entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
     }
     return entityManager;
     }
```

But when i hit first time then i am getting data and response able connect database but in second time when i hit then it give exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed`

And i am getting Exception here

```
entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

At this line please suggest me how to fix this issue i have to load mysql user id and password at server startup time .

Comment: Is it possible to post full code.

Comment: @MeiyappanKannappa http://paste.ofcode.org/Md5p22rcfXuaYCYXC5pcfN please check this DBmanger class